# Replace values in dataframe where updated versions are in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, something like this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Identity': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Notes': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Identity': [4, 8],
    'Value': [0, 128],
    })

In[3]: df1
Out[3]: 
   Identity  Value Notes
0         3      1     a
1         4      2     b
2         5      3     c
3         6      4     d
4         7      5     e
5         8      6     f
6         9      7     g

In[4]: df2
Out[4]: 
   Identity  Value
0         4      0
1         8    128
```

I'd like to use df2 to overwrite df1 but only where values exist in df2, so I end up with:

```
   Identity  Value Notes
0         3      1     a
1         4      0     b
2         5      3     c
3         6      4     d
4         7      5     e
5         8    128     f
6         9      7     g
```

I've been searching through all the various merge, combine, join functions etc, but I can't seem to find one that does what I want.  Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Use `replace` instead `map`

Comment: another way `df1['Value'] = df1['Identity'].map(df2.set_index('Identity')['Value']).fillna(df1['Value'])`

Comment: When there's just one column I'd go with: `df1.loc[df1.Identity.isin(df2.Identity), 'Value'] = df2.Value.values` which is slightliy better `690 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop` than all answers in this and other topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1['Value'] = df1['Identity'].map(df2.set_index('Identity')['Value']).fillna(df1['Value'])
```

Or try `reset_index` with `reindex` and `set_index` with `fillna`:

```
df1['Value'] = df2.set_index('Identity').reindex(df1['Identity'])
                  .reset_index(drop=True)['Value'].fillna(df1['Value'])
```

---

```
>>> df1
   Identity  Value Notes
0         3    1.0     a
1         4    0.0     b
2         5    3.0     c
3         6    4.0     d
4         7    5.0     e
5         8  128.0     f
6         9    7.0     g
>>>
```

This fills missing rows in `df2` with `NaN` and fills the `NaN`s with `df1` values.

Comment: wiki time? it is dupe.